# big speed difference on a network link with and without VPN tunnel

Tags: vpn, performance, bandwidth, site-to-site-vpn, network-speed

***Scenario:***

- We have a network link between two offices.
- The link is provided by a third party company through a VLAN on their
  network, but to us it is totally transparent -as if we had a simple
  ethernet cable going from one location to the other-.
- We have one router at each side of the link, with 3 VPN tunnels in
  between the two.

***The test:***
*programs used:* LanSpeedTest with 100MB transfer setting. I also transferred a 2GB file with Teracopy and checked the average speed (and the result was the same of LanSpeedTest).

- When I test the speed of the network link with the routers in place,
  with one laptop directly connected to the router on each side, I
  consistently get ~30/35Mbps.
- But if I take out the routers and I test the link connecting the
  laptops directly to the ethernet cable at each side, I consistently
  get ~85/88Mbps.

It's quite a big performance hit, and I would tend to think that the VPN tunnels are responsible for the slow down.

**Is it normal that this configuration (two routers with three VPN tunnels between them) takes away so much bandwidth?**

***More info:***

- The VPN type is IPSec and the encryption algorithm used is AES128.
- The routers model is Zyxel USG200 and Zyxel USG1000, and their CPU, memory, and storage use is well within normal
  limits. ADP,IDP,antivirus,content filter and anti-spam are disabled on both routers.
- The nominal bandwidth of the network link is 100Mbps.
- The network link in question is supplied by a third party company (the building in between our two offices). Basically it passes through their network as a VLAN, but the VLAN is completely transparent to us (e.g. no configuration required on our side, just like one single cable from end to end).

Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately) I cannot directly test different routers configurations as I'm not the person in charge of it.

Comment: What kind of routers are they? Older ones may not cope so well with the overhead a VPN gives.

Comment: Is this an IPSec VPN, I presume?

Comment: OK, I'll say it: The fact that you don't need the routers to establish connectivity between both offices tells me that the network transits a "private" network through the third party rather than being routed through the internet, so why do you want/need the VPN?

Comment: The USG 200 is only rated for 40Mbps if AV/IDP are enabled. Check your settings.

Comment: @joeqwerty  we use the encrypted VPNs exactly because the data transits through a third party network over which we have no control.. For what we know they might just want to spy on us :-) [however unlikely]

Comment: @NathanC they are Zyxel USG200 and USG1000, they are new, and from what I understand they are quite capable models.

Comment: @EEAA yes, IPSec VPN..

Comment: @MichaelHampton ADP,IDP,antivirus,content filter and anti-spam are all disabled on both routers.

Comment: What sort of settings were you using to test the bandwidth? VPN encrypted packets have a smaller "payload" and that can cause fragmentation, and a rather inefficient usage of the bandwidth.. Remember, you also have the overhead of the VLAN reducing packet size (however minimal)..

Comment: @NickW I used a program called LanSpeedTest with the setting of 100MB transfer.  I also used Teracopy to transfer a 2GB file and then I checked the average transfer speed. Finally, I checked the PING, and I constantly got <1ms withouth routers, and 2ms, 3ms with the routers.

Comment: @NickW the PING measurements above are taken in a moment without any other network activity.

Comment: Try testing the bandwidth over the VPN tunnel with iptraf using different packet sizes. Firewalls/vpn routers are limited by the packets per second, so you'll get this kind of performance if your applications use very small segment sizes.